# paypal integration with node.JS is not deducting any money from either account (merchant or buyer)

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have tried to integrated paypal-rest-sdk in NodeJS.
While making a payment I don't get any error and customer is redirected to `/succcess` route.
The Major problem is the amount is deducted & added in payer and payee account respectively.

My code is:

```
import paypal from 'paypal-rest-sdk';
let paypal_config ={
  "port": 5000,
  "api": {
    "port": "",
    "host": "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
    "client_id": "my client id",
    "client_secret": "my client secret"
  }
}`
`  app.post('/paynow', function(req, res) {
    // paypal payment configuration.
    var payment = JSON.stringify({
      intent: 'sale',
      payer: {
        payment_method: 'paypal'
      },
      redirect_urls: {
        return_url: app.locals.baseurl + '/success',
        cancel_url: app.locals.baseurl + '/cancel'
      },
      transactions: [{
        amount: {
          total: parseInt(req.body.amount, 10),
          currency: req.body.currency
        },
        description: req.body.description
      }]
    });
    paypal.payment.create(payment, function(error, payment) {
      if(error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        if(payment.payer.payment_method === 'paypal') {
          req.paymentId = payment.id;
          var redirectUrl;
          console.log(payment);
          for(var i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
            var link = payment.links[i];
            if(link.method === 'REDIRECT') {
              redirectUrl = link.href;
            }
          }
          res.redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong but I don't get any and i am redirected to "/success" end-point.

Comment: What is the problem? You don't get any (what)..?

Comment: the problem is the amount is not deducted from the paypal(sandbox) account but the transaction is shown as completed successfully .